# TypeError: Object #<MongoClient> has no method 'db'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I am new at **node.js, mongodb, express** and having so much trouble to set up database. My code (app.js) is given below

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

    app.engine('html', cons.swig);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017));
// error occurs here
var db = mongoclient.db('course');

app.get('/', function(req, res){  
   // Find one document in our collection
   db.collection('hello_combined').findOne({}, function(err, doc) {
      if(err) throw err;
      res.render('hello', doc);
   });
});

mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {
   if(err) throw err;
   app.listen(8080);
});
```

When I run this code **node app.js**, I have the following error:

```
sabbir@sabbir-pc:~/nodejs/hello_express$ node app.js

 /home/sabbir/nodejs/hello_express/app.js:12
 var db = mongoclient.db('course');
                      ^
 TypeError: Object #<MongoClient> has no method 'db'
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sabbir/nodejs/hello_express  /app.js:12:22)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
   at startup (node.js:119:16)
   at node.js:935:3
```

NB: I am using **Ubuntu 14.04.02**, My **node.js version v0.10.38** and **MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2**

**Edit**
I also use the following code ::

```
var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017));

mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {
  if(err) throw err;
  var db = mongoclient.db('course');

  app.get('*', function(req, res){
      res.send('Page Not Found', 404);
  });
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // Find one document in our collection
    db.collection('hello_combined').findOne({}, function(err, doc) {
       if(err) throw err;
       res.render('hello', doc);
    });
  });
  app.listen(8080);
});
```

And I have the following error ::

```
 sabbir@sabbir-pc:~/nodejs/hello_express$ node app.js

 /home/sabbir/nodejs/hello_express/app.js:13
 mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {
             ^
 TypeError: Object #<MongoClient> has no method 'open'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sabbir/nodejs/hello_express/app.js:13:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

Comment: Try to open a connection first before calling the `db` method

Comment: Please try reading the document, for example the [Node.js driver tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connecting/). You don't use a `db` method to access a db.

Answer (score 5):

If one want to use MongoClient, that allows making Connections to MongoDB, do it as:

```
     var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
     test = require('assert');
     var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
     Connect using MongoClient
     MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
     var testDb = db.db('test'); //use can chose the database here
     db.close();
    });
```

**Another Method:**

However if you want to use express and want to associate the variable with the app object and to get initialize with the app, one can do it as:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
cons = require('consolidate'),
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
MongoServer = require('mongodb').Server,
Db = require('mongodb').Db,
db = new Db('pcat', new MongoServer('localhost', 27017, { 'native_parser': true }));

db.open(function (err, asdf) {
app.listen(8080);
console.log("The server is listening at port 8080");
});
```

***Package.json**:

- "consolidate":"^0.13.1",
- "express": "^3.4.4",
- "mongodb": "^2.0.40",
- "swig": "^1.4.2"*

Comment: MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/your_database_name', function(err, dbConnection) { console.log("database created and connected"); });

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
npm install mongodb@1.4
```

EDIT:

The mongoclient.db() is not in the latest version of the mongodb node library.

Comment: Certainly it seems that the function is no longer available on new versions, I would like to know why, my best guess it that it was just too "complicated" to create a new variable for that, look how its done on the newer versions (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/), db is referenced on the "MongoClient.connect" function.